# uikit autocomplete custom template in twig

Tags: symfony, autocomplete, uikit, twig

I am working on Symfony. I read the documentation for the UIkit autocompleter at [documentation Autocomplete Custom Template](http://getuikit.com/docs/autocomplete.html)

And the syntax for custom templating that is provided in the example is:

```
 <div class="uk-autocomplete uk-form" data-uk-autocomplete="{source:'my-autocomplete.json'}">
    <input type="text">
    <script type="text/autocomplete">
        <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-autocomplete uk-autocomplete-results">
            {{~items}}
            <li data-value="{{ $item.value }}">
                <a>
                    {{ $item.title }}
                    <div>{{{ $item.text }}}</div>
                </a>
            </li>
            {{/items}}
        </ul>
    </script>
</div>
```

But the problem i am facing is that, i am **using TWIG** for templating, and in twig curly brackets '**{{ }}**' are for calling twig functionalities. Thus when i use the code for the Custom templating, i get **Compilation Errors**.

I tried putting the code for custom templating in a javascript file, and 'importing' the script right after the form but it didnt work ex:

**Javascript file: header_autocomplete.js**

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-autocomplete uk-autocomplete-results">
    {{~items}}
    <li data-value="{{ $item.value }}">
        <a>
            {{ $item.title }}
            <div>{{{ $item.text }}}</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/items}}
</ul>
```

And i imported the script in the twig template as follows:

**html.twig file: index.html.twig**

```
<div class="uk-form uk-autocomplete" data-uk-autocomplete="{source:'tmp/header_autocomplete.json'}" id="form-search"> 
    <input class="uk-form-width-large" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <script type="text/autocomplete" src="header_autocomplete.js"></script>
    <button class="uk-button"><i class="uk-icon-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

But this didnt seem to work, i just get an empty dropdown menu for results.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html)